# wifi connection failure iPad

Tags: ios, wifi, nsurl, kqueue

I am developing an app which communicates with server. Often communication drops and works again only when i terminate the app and relaunch it. from the device logs i found this error message

```
 <Error>: tcp_connection_destination_setup_socket_events 211705 kqueue() failed Too many open files
```

i went through the following [post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6473762),but did not understand anything, help me out on the root cause and how to fix this .

Comment: That thread doesn't really seem applicable to your situation. I googled your exact error message "[kqueue() failed Too many open files](https://www.google.com.au/?gws_rd=ssl#q=kqueue()+failed+Too+many+open+files)" and there appears to be a lot of results for that, have you tried any of them?

Comment: results where related to OSX and also where not usefull

Comment: From the message my guess would be that you are "leaking" sockets. Look carefully at your code and make sure that you are either reusing connections or properly costing your connection before opening a new one

Comment: it is just a nsurl connection which is sent every minute